# Why can i not override the body overflow-y with a media query?

Tags: media-queries, overflow

I might make a obvious mistake but somehow I am stuck with the following:

only for large screens i don't want the vertical scrollbar so i have this simple css:

```
 @media (min-width : 2000px) {
            // hacky
            body {
                overflow-y:hidden !important;
                }
           .mt-5{
                    margin-top: 80px !important;
                }
                .mb-5{
                     margin-bottom: 80px !important;
                    }
...more style definitions
```

but somehow this doesn't work

i am using chrome's toggle device bar tool to switch between different resolutions. All other css definitions for > 2000px are there, only body doesn't seem to be set??

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media (min-width : 2000px) {

            body {
                overflow-y:hidden !important;
                }
           .mt-5{
                    margin-top: 80px !important;
                }
                .mb-5{
                    margin-bottom: 80px !important;
                }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add the closing tag of the media query and please use css comment tag.

Comment: Sorry i do have the closing tag. I just didn't want to put all the definitions

Answer (score 0):

Did you set 100% height for html and body, like this:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

And also for possible other child elements inside `body` which span the whole height of `body`?

Otherwise one of them will get a scroll bar (not necessarily body, but it will look very similar)